# Accessing @nuxtjs/axios module instance in an ES6 module

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, axios, nuxt.js

I have installed `@nuxtjs/axios` package and configured it in `modules` section of `nuxt.config.js` like below

```
modules: [
  '@nuxtjs/axios',
]
```

I am able to access the axios instance in `vuex` and `components`. But now I want to access it in an ES6 module. I tried below imports to get the instance but API call is not triggered or any error thrown.

```
import axios from '@nuxtjs/axios'
```

and

```
import axios from 'axios'
```

Comment: Try installing axios (`npm i axios`)

Comment: As said above, you'll need to install the regular `axios` if you want to use it outside of the Vue context.

Comment: @kissu But then I will have two axios packages installed

Comment: Yep, I don't see the issue since they serve different purposes.